# Laravel Query - Obtener listado de columnas

Tags: php, laravel

Soy nuevo en Laravel y en mi modelo tengo una funcion la cual ejecuto una query "compleja":

```
$result = Activities::
            from("Rn_Appointments as t1")
            ->leftJoin("Employee as t2", "t2.Employee_Id", "=", "t1.Rn_Employee_Id")
            ->leftJoin("Company as t3", "t3.Company_Id", "=", "t1.Company")
            ->selectRaw("
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.Employee_Id) as '#',
                t2.Rn_Descriptor AS Empleado,
                LTRIM(RTRIM(t3.Company_Name)) AS Compañia,
                CAST(t1.Appt_Date as date) as Fecha_programada,
                CAST(t1.Activity_Completed_Date as date) as Fecha_realizada,
                CASE
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 0 THEN 'Reunión'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 1 THEN 'Tarea'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 2 THEN 'Llamada'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 3 THEN 'Mensaje'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 4 THEN 'Documentación'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 5 THEN 'Nota'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 6 THEN 'Demostracion'
                    WHEN Activity_Type = 7 THEN 'Llamada inbound'
                END AS Tipo
            ")
            ->whereRaw("
                t1.Assigned_To = (
                    SELECT CAST(Rn_Employee_User_Id as int) as PK_Usuario
                    FROM Employee
                    WHERE Employee_Id = CAST( ? AS INT)
                )
                AND Activity_Type IN (0,2)
                AND CASE              
                    WHEN ? = 'De Cierre' THEN CAST(t1.Activity_Completed_Date as date)
                    ELSE CAST(t1.Appt_Date as date)
                END = ?
            ")
            ->setBindings($filtros);
```

El resultado lo obtengo facil con `$result->get();` y el listado de columnas con `array_keys(json_decode($result[0], true))`, todo bien hasta aca...

Mi problema con esto es cuando no hay resultado de la query, entonces en `$result` me retorna `false` y no puedo capturar el listado de columnas de esta query y lo necesito para alimentar la cabecera de una tabla dinamica en mi vista.

Existe alguna forma en la que pueda capturar previamente (de forma dinamica en el caso de modificar esta query) las columnas aunque el resultado de la query no encuentre registros?

Comment: Sin meterme mucho en qué hace la consulta o en por qué querrías los nombres de las columnas de la BD... Y si haces otra consulta sacando los where y los filtros? Algo así `$columns = array_keys(Activities::from("Rn_Appointments as t1")->leftJoin(...)->leftJoin(...)->selectRaw(...)->first()->toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Los bindings (de selects, de wheres y de joins) están en el query builder. Puedes declarar la consulta en una variable (que no es la misma de los resultados), y usarla para obtener una instancia del builder.

```
$query = Activities::
        from("Rn_Appointments as t1")
        ->leftJoin("Employee as t2", "t2.Employee_Id", "=", "t1.Rn_Employee_Id")
        ->leftJoin("Company as t3", "t3.Company_Id", "=", "t1.Company")
        ->selectRaw(" < SQL muy complejo > ");

$result = $query-> whereRaw(" < sql más complejo >")->get();
```

La primera variable es una instancia de Eloquent Builder. A ésta puedes pedirle la instancia de Database Builder:

```
$dbBuilder = $query->getQuery();
```

La propiedad "columns" es pública. Es un array de instancias de `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression`.

Si yo declaré mi query como:

```
  ->selectRaw('id as correlativo, alias as name')
```

Entonces `$columns` contiene

```
 [
   'id as correlativo, alias as name'
 ]
```

Lo cual sirve de muy poco. Pero si tú declaras tu query como

```
  ->selectRaw(
     [
      'id as correlativo', 
      'alias as name'
     ]
  )
```

Entonces `$columns` contendrá

```
 [
   'id as correlativo', 
   'alias as name'
 ]
```

Lo cual significa que en tu caso, si quieres obtener un array de columnas, tendrás que modificar tu `selectRaw` para pasar las columnas como array.

```
    ->selectRaw([
       "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.Employee_Id) as '#'",
       "t2.Rn_Descriptor AS Empleado",
       "LTRIM(RTRIM(t3.Company_Name)) AS Compañia",
    ])
```

Para convertir el array de expressions en una colección de strings puedes hacer:

```
     collect($query->getQuery()->columns)
           ->map(fn($expression) => $expression->getValue())
```

Es posible que haya otro camino para obtener esto mismo separando los alias (AS) de la fórmula que representan. Yo me conformaría con hacer algo como:

```
     collect($query->getQuery()->columns)
         ->map(fn($expression) => $expression->getValue())
         ->map(fn($column) => array_pop(explode(' AS ',$column)))
```

Comment: Gracias por responder y me paso algo raro.
Segui tus primeros pasos, separa la query y el result, y al querer obtener `$query->getQuery()->columns` obtengo un objeto vacio `{}`, absolutamente sin nada

Comment: hmmm yo lo probé en mi local antes de responder, pero por si acaso, acá está el método. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L299 A lo mejor  necesitas que tenga un binding para poblar $columna

Comment: es que no estoy usando Laravel en si, sino un framework basado en laravel (7 u 8 creo), llamado LeafPHP y de principio me ha servido bastante, pero luego se ha vuelto un dolor de cabeza... Y el problema es que en el proyecto que me pidieron en la empresa, exigen que lo use...

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver. Leaf reemplaza al container, pero no tiene un orm. En tu proyecto seguro tienes instalado eloquent, aunque no uses el container de laravel

Comment: Mira, te dare un ejemplo que me ha dado muchos problemas. Este proyecto debiese tener configurado varias conexiones a base de datos. Segun la documentacion de Leaf, puedo crear estas configuraciones en el archivo `database.php` (como en laravel), el asunto es, cuando configuro una con su nombre y luego la quiero instansear en un modelo usando `protected $connection = 'sql_srv_2';`... este me da error: `Database connection [sql_srv_2] not configured.`

Comment: no encontré alusión a database.php en el sitio de ellos. Pero la propiedad mágica `connection` la recibe la clase ConnectionManager, que a su vez intenta pedirle la configuración de esa conección a la clase ConfigRepository. Por lo que miré de Leaf dudo mucho que esté llenando el ConfigRepository. Más bien me suena que si logras conectarte hoy en día es porque se está leyendo el .env directamente

Comment: Disculpa que moleste a este nivel, pero tu me podrias aconsejar con algun framework parecido a laravel el cual sea liviano con "patron mvc" y que no necesite algun complemento especial para subirlo a un servidor? (O sea, solo copiar el proyecto y subirlo directo a la tipica carpeta public_html)... Opte por Leaf justamente porque me permitia esto, pero ha sido solo dolores de cabeza entre las conexiones a la base de datos, las queries y blade...

Comment: Yo haría el esfuerzo adicional para correr Laravel en el servidor antes que el esfuerzo adicional de adaptar cualquier otro framework para funcionar como Laravel. Pero si tuviera que elegir algo muy ligero y no necesitara un ORM, usaría Slim Framework.